# Key colors are different from what is on graph in JFreeChart line graph

Tags: java, graph, jfreechart

I've created a graph with 3 sets of data. They display correctly, and have the coloring/shape that I've specified. However, in the key the shapes correspond to the data points but the colors are completely different.

Has anyone run into this/have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that in my chartlabel getColor was being overriden, but not being looked for when I rendered the graph.